# Angular/CSS onload how to get the default tab active

Tags: css, angular, nav, mat-tab

I am creating a angular page which uses ***mat-tab-nav-bar*** and ***mat-tab-link***.

**dashborad.component.html**

```
<div><nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
    <a mat-tab-link [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a>
    <a mat-tab-link [routerLink]="['/admin']">Admin</a>
    <a mat-tab-link [routerLink]="['/order']">Orders</a>
    </nav></div>
  <div><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
```

**AppRoutingModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { HomeComponent} from './components/home/home.component';
import { AdminComponent} from './components/admin/admin.component';
import { OrdersComponent} from './components/orders/orders.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent ,
children: [
     {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent},
    {path: 'order', component: OrdersComponent},
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'}
]
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I am able to get page as I want except one thing. When the page gets loaded it shows the default page but the tab is not showing as selected. When I click a tab it becomes active and shows the same page.So would like to know how to achieve the requirement.

Comment: I already accepted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use routerLinkActive attribute for the same. Where this attribute adds a class name to active element and then you can add CSS to that class

Find the syntax:

```
<a routerLink="/user/bob" routerLinkActive="active-link">Bob</a>
```

Css:

```
.active-link
{
Color: Blue;
Font-size: 17;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing code snippet. I am new to angular , so it is helped.

Comment: You are most welcome..